# Flutter Card child content height is larger than its parent

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-card

I'm trying to use a `GridView` to handle displays for multiple `Card`, each `Card` contains of an `Image`. Unfortunately it turns out that the `Image` is taking a larger height than its parent (see attached picture for the details).

I'm pretty new to Flutter layout so any ideas why this is happening and how I can resolve this? I want the layout to be something like this:

- Display 2 cards on each line.
- The `Card` width or height should not be fixed.
- The `Image` height should be scaled according to its width.

[image]

```
class SquadSelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Team> teams;

  const SquadSelectionScreen({super.key, required this.teams});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Squads'),
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: teams
            .map(
              (team) => SquadView(team: team),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SquadView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Team team;

  const SquadView({super.key, required this.team});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        context.push('/squads/${team.code}');
      },
      child: Card(
        elevation: 1,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(team.imageUrl),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(team.name),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't put the code in the question. Can you give the code for the GridView.builder and the Card widgets?

Comment: @SeptianDika I updated the question with source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GridView.count` has a very visible drawback, namely the size of the aspect ratio of the grid will always be **one** (1:1 or Square) and can't be changed.

So if you look at the code above, you can't set an image with the same aspect ratio because the text will sink.

The first suggestion for me if you still want to use `GridView.count` is

1. Wrapping your `Image` with `AspectRatio` that has value higher than **one** (example set Ratio to 4/3, 5/3, 16/9, or landscape looks). Note: 4/3 = is higher than 1, 16/9 = is higher than 1, etc..
2. Then wrap the Text Widget with `Expanded()`

Example code:

```
class SquadView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Team team;

  const SquadView({super.key, required this.team});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Card(
        elevation: 1,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 4/3, // you can set the value to 16/9 or anything that result is higher than one
                child: Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(team.imageUrl),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, // set How the image looks to Fit
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(team.name, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I suggest you try `GridView.builder` or another GridView. You can look at the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

or this third package this will be good for to try [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). The flutter_staggered_grid_view is more flexible to create GridView with various size.